# Simple html dom error problem and fetching "file_get_contents(): Stream does not support seeking" problem

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, simple-html-dom

[image]

```
<?php
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use App\Models\Ajkerpatrika;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use Sunra\PhpSimple\HtmlDomParser;

class AjkerpatrikaController extends Controller
 {
    public function getIndex(){
        $url = "http://www.google.com/";
        $html = HtmlDomParser::file_get_html($url);
        $a= $html->find('title',0)->plaintext;
        echo $a;
        return view('welcome');
    }
  }``
?>
```

Here I Use the Simple Html Dom but I got a problem. When I comment on the line of HtmlDomParser then I got a view. Is it okay??

Comment: try this `HtmlDomParser::file_get_html($url, false, null, 0);`

Comment: I got this kind of problem    "preg_match(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 4"